# Account Should not have a duplicate contact

Tags: salesforce, apex

Hope you are doing great!!!

Can someone help me to achieve this logic.

the Logic is about the account should not have a duplicate contact(I have used lastName of the contact).

Below is the code

```
public static void duplicateLogicForAccContact(List<Contact> conList){
    Map<Id,String> accContactMap = new Map<Id,String>();
    for(Contact con:conList ){
        accContactMap.put(con.AccountId,con.LastName);
    }
    List<contact> contactAccountList = [SELECT Id,LastName,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN : accContactMap.keySet()];
    for(contact cons: contactAccountList){
        if(accContactMap.containsKey(cons.AccountId)){
            cons.LastName.addError('The Second Name you have entered is showing as duplicate in our DataBase');
        }
    }
}
```

The Error shows like Error: **"Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger Trigger_Example caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Trigger_Example: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors"**

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to add error to already saved recored let's say there is 1st contact is john doe so this is saved

then when you go for second time you are trying to save contact with the same name jhon doe then you are querying all contacts and addError to all of them so you are adding it to the 1st john doe, i have made some changes to the code below

```
enter code here
public static void duplicateLogicForAccContact(List<Contact> conList){
Map<Id,String> contactMap = new Map<String,Contact>();   
Map<Id,String> accContactMap = new Map<Id,String>();
for(Contact con:conList ){
    accContactMap.put(con.AccountId,con.LastName);
    contactMap.put(con.LastName,con);
}
List<contact> contactAccountList = [SELECT Id,LastName,AccountId FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId IN : accContactMap.keySet()];
for(contact cons: contactAccountList){
    if(accContactMap.containsKey(cons.AccountId)){
        contactMap.get(cons.LastName).LastName.addError('The Second Name you 
have entered is showing as duplicate in our DataBase');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Map<Id,String> contactMap = new Map<String,Contact>();   
previously it was added like this but i have changed like:
Map<String,Contact> contactMap = new Map<String,Contact>();
is this correct?